"Directory not empty" and "Input/output error" when "cd"/"ls" into certain dirs or "rm -rf" certain files of a mounted storage drive
I have a storage device (sda) where I stored some backups in its partition 1 (sda1). Disgracefully, I killed the process (rsync) that was backing up data into the mounted storage device and, I guess, creating a fault in the drive.
Now I am trying to undo the mess by removing all files from the backup dir. I can successfully remove most of the files and directories I backed up before the crash, although many don't want to be deleted and show Directory not empty or Input/output error. I guess these files are the ones that couldn't fully be copied into the backup directory because of me killing the rsync process.
Since I am using a server OS I can't use a GUI to throw these files into the paper bin and then flush it (as I've seen other people do with similar issues).
This is what I've tried for now:

umount the drive and fsck -f in /dev/sda1
smartctl -a /dev/sda1 which gave me the usual information, no errors in it.
Removing parent directories -> I get Directory not empty

More information:
In some cases I can't even ls:
/hooks$ ls -lha
ls: cannot access 'applypatch-msg.sample': Input/output error
ls: cannot access 'pre-receive.sample': Input/output error
total 8.0K
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4.0K Jun 13 11:37 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4.0K Jun 13 11:37 ..
-????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? applypatch-msg.sample
-????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? pre-receive.sample

These files are not important, it would be ideal if I could just remove them. The storage doesn't have important information either, I am just using it for testing purposes for now, so resetting it wouldn't be a problem, although I'd like to find a more elegant solution. Thank you!

Which filesystem is used on the disk? Generally fsck would have been the first (and second) suggestion, but in case it's NTFS, then Windows chkdsk would be the next thing to try.

It is using ext4 with a DOS partition table. Since I wasn't finding any "elegant" solutions, I reset the drive using dd. Then I recreated the ext4 filesystem metadata and now it is working. Moreover, other solutions that don't involve removing all data are always welcome!
